# What's the shortcut to move to other view in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, viewer

I'm trying to split-view in Notepad++ with Windows 10.

I use the mouse's right click to split the view, but I'm looking for the shortcut to do the same task but I didn't find it.

What is the shortcut to `Move to other view` in **Notepad++**?

Answer (score 4):

There is no shortcut defined for this operation.
[image]

You can add convenient combination as shortcut.